# filter data in a Table angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new with angular and I have data table and I want to filter data of each column.

I have a text column and I want when I type Xxx I return only the lines with the column value contains Xxx.

this is my filter:

```
<th >
    <input class="ui-g-7" type="text" id= "filterColumn1" name="filterColumn1" 
        (input)="filterColumn1($event)"/>
</th>
```

and in the ts code:

```
    public filterColumn1(event){
       this.myTemplateView  = this.myTemplateView  .filter(item=>item.column1.includes(event.target.value)).map(item=>item);
}
```

the myTemplateView is an array of data that contains many columns

any help please ? I'mnot getting data filtred when I type a word and when I reset the filter also (I delete what I entered )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to implement filtering functionality in Angular for a data table based on the input provided by the user. There are a couple of adjustments you can make to achieve this.

First, ensure that you're handling the filtering logic correctly in your TypeScript code. Secondly, make sure you're properly updating the view whenever the filter changes. Here's how you can improve your code:

HTML Template:

```
<th><input class="ui-g-7" type="text" id="filterColumn1" name="filterColumn1" 
    (input)="filterColumn1($event.target.value)"/></th>
```

Component TypeScript:

```
public filterColumn1(value: string) {
    this.filteredData = this.myTemplateView.filter(item => item.column1.includes(value));
}
```